# ESP32 - using 3.3V Dual relay

Tags: esp32, power-sources

I have an issue- which I guess is has some power issue.
I'm using [ESP32](https://www.ebay.com/itm/ESP-32S-ESP32-NodeMCU-Development-Board-2-4GHz-WIFI-Bluetooth-Dual-Mode/272656534488?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649) and a [3.3v Dual relay](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/3V-2-Channel-Relay-Module-3-3V-Optocoupler-Isolation-Module-Relay-Control-Board/32847869020.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.23a54c4dfruuA4).

My code is simple ( switch up and switch down ), and works fine.

The thing is that when all wires are connected between ESP32 and Relays, and then connecting ESP32 to USB cable from a 2A adapter to main, it just wont start ( I have a MQTT message send on boot ), **BUT** when I  first connect ESP32 to power ( same cable, adapter and so on ), and only then connect `VCC` and `GND` to relay - all is working fine ( buttons and MQTT ).

I tried it several times, and it is persistent

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 1) without a schematic it is insufficiently documented to be answerable anywhere 2) it sounds suspiciously like a duplicate of your other current question https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/3324/esp32-pullup-pulldown-resistors and 3) the question asked is about the circuitry surrounding the ESP32, **and not about the usage of the ESP32 for an IoT purpose**.

Comment: It is not the same question, and now I’m trying with esp32 board and it has different behavior. What schematic do you need? It is a 4 pin connection ( vcc gnd in1 in2 )

Comment: You need to show the connections of the relay to the ESP32.  And it likely is the same question - the most likely explanation is that your relay input is mis-configuring the ESP32 boot pins.  But regardless of that, the question is off topic here **as it is not about IoT**.